# Can the watchdog on an STM32F373 trigger a reset while the RESET pin is held high?

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi, reset, watchdog

The reset pin on an STM32 chip is being pulled high by a Raspberry Pi Zero W in the field via GPIO pin BCM 17.

Will the watchdog on the STM32 be capable of triggering a reset while the pin is being pulled high?

Answer (score 2):

No. The nRST pin of STM32 is not meant to be forced high externally, because it is bidirectional open-drain IO pin. Simplest way to avoid this is of course to set the RPI pin as input and only set it to low and output when resetting STM32, and back to input to release the reset.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the pin without a series resistor, probably not.

[image: simplified reset circuitry]

This image shows a simplified view of the internal reset circuitry. As you can see the internal resets produce a low pulse on the NRST pin. If you pull that high directly with a GPIO it is likely that the voltage will not go below the reset low level.

So you should place a series resistor in the NRST line. The internal pull up resistor is at least 25 kΩ. The reset is asserted when the NRST pin is pulled below 0.3 Vdd + 0.07 V.

So the external series resistor must be small enough, that you can produce a reset with your external pin and big enough that the internal switch can pull the line low.

The voltage divider equation helps us to get to a series resistor of 12 kΩ as a maximum value. There is no specification on how strong the internal switch can pull the line low, but I'd guess it's not a very weak switch. So I'd go for something in the 5 to 8 kΩ range.

Note that if you connect the pin to an external reset source, you might want to place a capacitor near the NRST pin to prevent accidental resets because of noise on the line.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpVauB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Instead of using a resistor, you can also use a diode with a low enough forward voltage (below 0.3 Vdd + 0.07 V, like a Schottky diode). This will prevent the pin from being pulled high actively by the external device but still allows it to be pulled low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs4nET.png)</sup>

Comment: Using an open collector driver or software implementation thereof is a far more sound solution avoiding the need to balance resistor values.

Comment: A schottky diode would just work instead of randomly determining suitable resistor value. External pull-ups are generally not even shown on ST guides, and if they are, they are specified as not mounted component.

Comment: @Justme yeah a diode with low enough forward voltage would work as well.